# data grid in wpf wont update itself no matter what

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

so i want to insert an obj into a table of sql using linq to sql and when i submit the change the grid view wont update itself no matter what
it shows the data at first but the new obj wont show up
data comes from a dbml ,

i would really appreciate a hand

```
namespace Wpf_Main_Storage
{
    public partial class SellWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Sell_factor> TableData { get; }

        public SellWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.TableData = new ObservableCollection<Sell_factor>();
        }
        private readonly dataclassDataContext db = new dataclassDataContext();

        private void Grid_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dg_1.ItemsSource = TableData;
            Combo_sherkat.ItemsSource = db.sellers.Select(c => c.name);
        }
        
        private void Combo_sherkat_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetKala();
        }

        private void Combo_kala_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeUnit();
        }
        public void SubmitNewBuyFactor()
        {
            Sell_factor jadid = new Sell_factor();
            jadid.seller_company = Combo_sherkat.SelectedItem.ToString();
            jadid.sell_price = int.Parse(txt_sellprice.Text);
            jadid.product_name = Combo_kala.SelectedItem.ToString();
            jadid.unit = lbl_unit.Text;
            jadid.buy_price = int.Parse(txt_buyprice.Text);
            jadid.description = txt_description.Text;
            jadid.amount = int.Parse(txt_amount.Text);
            jadid.sum_finance = ((int.Parse(txt_sellprice.Text)) - (int.Parse(txt_buyprice.Text)) - (int.Parse(txt_discount.Text))) * (int.Parse(txt_amount.Text));
            jadid.date = date_date.SelectedDate;
            jadid.discount = int.Parse(txt_discount.Text);

            db.Sell_factors.InsertOnSubmit(jadid);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            this.TableData.Add(jadid);
        }
        
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SubmitNewBuyFactor();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dg_1.Items.Refresh();` is not required and should be removed.
`Dg_1.ItemsSource = null;` is not required and should be removed.

`DataContext.SubmitChanges` is obviously generating an error and the transactions is rolled back or the query is not executed (because of table/entity errors).
You should check your entities and table for errors. E.g. your table must have a primary key defined to enable insert/update using LINQ to SQL.

You can use `DataContext.GetChangeSet` to actually check if changes have been committed.

Alternatively omit LINQ to SQL and use [`db.ExecuteCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#examples) to execute a pure SQL query (e.g. in case you don't want or can't define a primary key for the table).

---

To fix the `DataGrid` update issue assign a `ObservableCollection` to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`.
`ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which will atomatically update every `ItemsControl` when an item is added/removed/moved/inserted:

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Sell_factor> TableData { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
 
        this.TableData = new ObservableCollection<Sell_factor>();
    }

    public void SubmitNewBuyFactor()
    {
        Sell_factor jadid = new Sell_factor();
        jadid.seller_company = Combo_sherkat.SelectedItem.ToString();
        jadid.sell_price = int.Parse(txt_sellprice.Text);
        jadid.product_name = Combo_kala.SelectedItem.ToString();
        jadid.unit = lbl_unit.Text;
        jadid.buy_price = int.Parse(txt_buyprice.Text);
        jadid.description = txt_description.Text;
        jadid.amount = int.Parse(txt_amount.Text);
        jadid.sum_finance = ((int.Parse(txt_sellprice.Text)) - (int.Parse(txt_buyprice.Text)) - (int.Parse(txt_discount.Text))) * (int.Parse(txt_amount.Text));
        jadid.date = date_date.SelectedDate;
        jadid.discount = int.Parse(txt_discount.Text);

        db.Sell_factors.InsertOnSubmit(jadid);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        // Update the DataGrid
        this.TableData.Add(jadid);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitNewBuyFactor();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <DataGrid x:Name="Dg_1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TableData}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222309/discussion-on-answer-by-bioniccode-data-grid-in-wpf-wont-update-itself-no-matter).